# Can we see more of the Developer Story technologies?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Currently I'm trying to update the technologies that I've worked with at my current employer. Doing this I ran into not being able to see an overview of all my technologies while I'm trying to edit them. This is rather frustrating, because that way it's hard to tell if I have any duplicates in them (or if that's not possible, see if I have similiar technologies listed). Here's an example of what I'm looking at:
[image: free hand boys]

It would be nice if this area would either expand based on the current items, be scrollable or draggable like a text-area.

That being said I also noticed a bug when trying to move up through the tags that, when adding a new one (in my case rabbitmq), it would sometimes cut-off or make my recently added tag dissappear. Don't have any reproducable steps, so that might just have been me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks very much for your report. We've added a scrollbar to the technologies section. This fix will be going out shortly with our next production build.

Comment: [Here's a duplicate from ~4 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242647/make-the-technologies-tag-editor-multi-line)